# 3 Different tables have same Foreign Key, How to select

Tags: mysql, left-join, yii2-model

Supposed I have 3 different tables which have identical Foreign Key like below:-

1. Table One **product_unit**

   ```
   | id  |  product_id  |  weight |  status_id  |
   |:----|--------------|---------|------------:|
   |  1  |      4       |   300   |      1      |
   |  2  |      5       |   120   |      2      |
   ```
2. Table Two **product_package**

   ```
   | id  |  product_id  |  weight |  status_id  |
   |:----|--------------|---------|------------:|
   |  1  |      4       |   1.2   |      1      |
   |  2  |      5       |   480   |      1      |
   ```
3. Table Three **product_carton**

   ```
   | id  |  product_id  |  weight |  status_id  |
   |:----|--------------|---------|------------:|
   |  1  |      4       |  10.2   |      1      |
   |  2  |      5       |   4.8   |      2      |
   ```

Where table **product** and **status** table as shown below:-

a. **product** table

```
    | id  |     name      |
    |:----|--------------:|
    |  4  |  Choco Cake   |
    |  5  | Hazelnut Bun  |
```

b. **status** table

```
    | id  |  description  |
    |:----|--------------:|
    |  1  |   Available   |
    |  2  |  Unavailable  |
```

How can I get **all status** from those 3 tables (product_unit, product_package & product_carton) with **1 query** ?

So far, I'm able to do this:-

```
$product_info = Product::find()
->select([
      'product.name AS productName',
      'product_unit.weight AS weightUnit',
      'product_package.weight AS weightPackage',
      'product_carton.weight AS weightCarton', 
      'status.description AS statusDesc'])
->leftJoin('product_unit', 'product.id = product_unit.product_id')
->leftJoin('product_package', 'product.id = product_package.product_id')
->leftJoin('product_carton', 'product.id = product_carton.product_id')
->leftJoin('status', 'status.id = product_unit.status_id')
->asArray()
->all();
```

With **above query** I can get **'statusDesc'** from **product_unit table ONLY**, since I **'leftJoin()' status table with product_unit table**.

How can I **JOIN** the other **2 tables (product_package & product_carton)** and get the **statusDesc** from them also? Is there any way I can do this with **1 Query**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$product_info = Product::find()
->select([
      'product.name AS productName',
      'product_unit.weight AS weightUnit',
      'product_package.weight AS weightPackage',
      'product_carton.weight AS weightCarton', 
      's1.description AS status_unit_Desc'])
      's2.description AS status_package_Desc'])
      's3.description AS status_carton_Desc'])
->leftJoin('product_unit', 'product.id = product_unit.product_id')
->leftJoin('product_package', 'product.id = product_package.product_id')
->leftJoin('product_carton', 'product.id = product_carton.product_id')
->leftJoin('status AS s1', 's1.id = product_unit.status_id')
->leftJoin('status AS s2', 's2.id = product_package.status_id')
->leftJoin('status AS s3', 's3.id = product_carton.status_id')
->asArray()
->all();
```

PS. Maybe innerJoin will be more suitable then leftJoin?

Comment: haha. Why didn't I think of this? So simple. By the way thanks @Akina